# Grammar and sentence structure "The more... the more"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Could someone help me revise this sentence? Does this sentence make sense to you guys?

> "The more the perception of family support, the more Mandarin favorable the language use policy at home, and/or the more years of family support for formal CHL, the higher the students’ CHL proficiency tends to be."

PS: CHL here stands for Chinese Heritage Language

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to say

> The more family support at home, the more Mandarin favorable the language policy is.

or

> The more *the* years of family support for formal CHL, the higher/*(more)* the student's CHL proficiency tends to be.

Comment: Ahh, Peter! Hi there!!

Comment: Hiya, I modified your sentences

Comment: Really nice to hear from you again~~

Comment: Hope all is well with you!